Solve for h given $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^h \cdot n < n_0 \leq \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{h-1} \cdot n$
The recursion tree generated from the following recurrence relation
$$
T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{3}\right) + T\left(\frac{2n}{3}\right) + \Phi(n)
$$
has, for some $n \geq n_0$, a depth $h$ given as a solution to the following inequality
$$
\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^h \cdot n < n_0 \leq \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{h-1} \cdot n
$$
I need to find the depth $h$ thus I tried to calculate it by applying the  logarithm with base $2\over 3$, but I am stuck at the following seemingly impossible inequality
$$
h < \log_{\frac{2}{3}} \left(\frac{n_0}{n}\right) \leq h - 1.
$$
As a hint, I am told that in order to solve for $h$ the above inequality, it is advisable to use either of the following identities:
$$
x -1 \lt \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$$ and $$x \leq \lceil x \rceil \lt x+1.
$$
This problem is taken from from Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein, Introduction to Algorithms, The MIT Press, 2009, chapter 4 where it is stated that $$h = \left\lfloor \log_{\frac{3}{2}} \left(\frac{n}{n_0}\right) \right\rfloor + 1$$

Turning my comment into an answer.
Remember that $\log_{2/3}(x)=\frac{\log x}{\log 2/3}$ and since $\log(2/3)<0$
you're dividing by a negative number, thus your inequality is (of course) the other way around:
$$h>\log_{2/3}(n_0/n)\geq h−1 \tag{1}$$
or
$$h-1 \leq \log_{2/3}(n_0/n) < h \tag{2}$$
Let $x = \log_{2/3}(n_0/n)$.
We know that $h$ is an integer, but so is $h-1$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$. Since there is no integer between $h$ and $h-1$, and $x$ is a number in between them, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ must be equal to $h-1$:
$$ h-1 = \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x < h$$
and
$$h = \lfloor \log_{2/3}(n_0/n) \rfloor + 1$$.

I applied log base 2/3 to each term in the inequality $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^h  < n_0/n  \leq \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{h-1} $, thus, did not explicitly divide by negative number. I did not think of flipping the inequality but applying function log with base less than 1 does flip the signs per definition of log function. thanks.
